# How should I configure the hosting server to upload a file from Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, file-upload, server, configuration

I want to create a file directory for my Flutter mobile application and upload files (any kind of images or pdf files).

I use the following code for selecting and uploading the file to the server :

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

class fileUpload extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: UploadScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class UploadScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UploadScreenState createState() => _UploadScreenState();
}

class _UploadScreenState extends State<UploadScreen> {
  File? _selectedFile;

  Future<void> _selectFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();

    if (result != null) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedFile = File(result.files.single.path!);
      });
    }
  }

  Future<void> _uploadFile() async {
    if (_selectedFile == null) {
      print('no files picked');
      return;
    }

    var uri = Uri.parse('http://myhostingdomain.com/specialdirectory'); // Sunucunun URL'si

    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', _selectedFile!.path));

    var response = await request.send();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('successfully uploaded.');
    } else {
      print('Error returned: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sample file upload page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _selectFile,
              child: Text('Choose a file'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            _selectedFile != null
                ? Text('selected file: ${_selectedFile!.path}')
                : Text('no files found'),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _uploadFile,
              child: Text('upload the file'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I run my mobile application everything looks file and file seems uploaded. But when I check the file server at the hosting destination, there is no file uploaded.

I believe I have to configure the public hosting server and send the authentication before I start the uploading the file.

How should I update my code to add the credentials while connecting the destination and additionally how should I configure the hosting server to accept uploadings?

Thank you

there are several solutions I found over internet but not including the credentials for a public hosting server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading a file is a multi-step process that requires work on the client and server side:

Server Side:

Create a folder to save your uploaded files. Make sure the folder is in your website directory and you can call it something like: UploadsFolder

For this example, I am using localhost.

Write the following code into a php file and call it uploadData.php

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    try {

        // File handling
        $file = $_FILES['file'];
        $fileName = $file['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
        

        // Move the uploaded file to the desired directory
        $uploadsDirectory = 'UploadsFolder/';
        $targetPath = $uploadsDirectory . $fileName;

        move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $targetPath);

  
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        http_response_code(500); // Internal Server Error
    } 
}
?>
```

Client side:

write the following commands in your terminal to install the http and file_picker packages in flutter:

**flutter pub add http 

flutter pub add file_picker**

Use the following code to upload your file

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';
void main()=>runApp(const MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: 
        Center(child:
        FileUploader()
      )),
    );
  }
}
// as widgets

class FileUploader extends StatefulWidget {
  const FileUploader({super.key});
  @override
  State<FileUploader> createState() => _FileUploaderState();
}

class _FileUploaderState extends State<FileUploader> {
String? fileName;
PlatformFile? selectedFile;

Future<void> _uploadFile() async {
    if (selectedFile == null) {
      print('no files picked');
      return;
    }

    var uri = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2/demoProject/uploadData.php'); // Sunucunun URL'si

    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
    request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', selectedFile!.path??""));

    var response = await request.send();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('successfully uploaded.');
    } else {
      print('Error returned: ${response.reasonPhrase}');
    }
  }



pickFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
    if (result != null) {
      PlatformFile? file = result.files.first;
    setState(() {
      selectedFile=file;
      fileName=file.name;
print("fileName is $fileName");
    });
    }
    return null;
  }  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
      
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
await pickFile();


}, child: const Text("Pick file to upload")),

ElevatedButton(onPressed: ()async{
if(selectedFile!=null){
    
await _uploadFile();
}
}, child: const Text("Upload selected file"))

    ],);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you dear Dany. Just want to highlight that, as far as I know dio will not be supported and maintanined any more since few months. That's why I didnt wish to use dio in my app.

Comment: Hi @EmsilNeumann , I am not sure if that has been confirmed yet, but if you're worried about Dio being discontinued, you can use the http package from your code. **I have edited my answer to use http instead of Dio, and everything else works as in my original answer.** Please upvote the answer if it works for you or let me know if it doesn't. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the answer & updates. But oddly and interestingly the code doesnt work when I try to change the Uri to my web hosting destination, which is a public hosting company and using CPanel. I allowed everything in the directories but i returns a socket error >>> Exception has occurred.
_ClientSocketException (ClientException with SocketException: Connection reset by peer (OS Error: Connection reset by peer, errno = 54), address = www.mysamplesite.com, port = 50397. I guess the problem may be related to the configuration at the hosting side.

Comment: In many solutions I noticed that developers put a php (or any other) web page to get the sent file. Does it mean, it's not the way to upload a file to the server directly (for example www.mysamplepsite.com/imageshare (imageshare folder under the main home page root). Or should I use ftp uri for directly copying a file to the destination folder, without a web page at the destination location?

Comment: I have used public hosting services before and I never run into any problems with using php.  The benefit of using a php file is that you can write code to insert data into databases, you can save links to files and access them later, you can manipulate the data etc.  **But if you want to use ftp, then you can look into this package which does exactly that without php: ** https://pub.dev/packages/ftpconnect

Comment: when I use ftp accounts, it dramatically reduces the performance at the first handshake and connection establishment (comparing with the regular HTTP method). On the other hand, when I remove the constraints at the server, it became more sensitive. Instead of that using a token for the webapi worked significiantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that writing a file (by uploading) directly to a remote server requires a lot of security constraints. If we remove the security constraints the zone (target directory) at the remote server becomes weak.
That's why many solutions offer creating an interface to upload a file to the server. Such as a web page or webapi.

I have created the following webapi app in python to get the file and write to the server.

```
@app.route('/api/uploadafile', methods=['GET','POST'])
def uploadtheFile():
if 'myfile' not in request.files:
    return 'file could not be uploaded.', 400

myfile = request.files['myfile']
if myfile.filename == '':
    return 'please specify the filename', 400


myfile.save('dirforReceivedfiles/' + myfile.filename)

return 'successfully uploaded', 200
```

then I call this api from my flutter application :

```
 Future<void> uploadthisFile(File myfile) async {
 var url = Uri.parse('http://remoteaddress:<port>/api/uploadfile'); //   Flask web API URL

 var stream = new http.ByteStream(myfile.openRead());
 var mylength = await myfile.length();

 var request = new http.MultipartRequest('POST', url);
 var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('myfile', stream, mylength,
  filename: path.basename(myfile.path));

 request.files.add(multipartFile);

 var response = await request.send();
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   print('Successfully uploaded');
 } else {
 print('Failed! Error is: ${response.statusCode}');
 }
 }
```

I tested this code above and successfully worked for both local and remote (hosting) servers.

You have to be careful for the following points :

1- the webapi is hosted and running at the remote server. Python webapi using flask, must be run at Apache or NGINX, doesn't work on IIS directly.

2- the directory (e.g. /receivedfiles ) must be accessbile for the webapi application at the remote server.

3- the file type and file size must be configured at the flutter (dart) code before sending. If you remove the constraints (limits), you are most likely receive weird error messages that you can see at server logs.